# Shell gt comparison of lines of a file

Tags: shell

I am trying to check if the lines of a file are greater than 2 I wrote this script :

```
  (wc -l myfile | cut -c  1) -gt 2
```

however I get the error : syntax error near expected token '-gt',any ideas why?

Comment: `-gt` is not a command, it's a parameter for `test` AKA `[`.

Answer (score 3):

To test whether a file has more than two lines in it:

```
if [ "$( wc -l <file )" -gt 2 ]; then echo 'more than two lines'; fi
```

You are missing the `$` in front of `(...)` and you're also missing the `if [ ... ]`.  You need `$( ... )`, a command substitution, because you want to do something with the output of the command.

Some would prefer the following syntax:

```
test "$( wc -l <file )" -gt 2 && echo 'more than two lines'
```

or just

```
[ "$( wc -l <file )" -gt 2 ] && echo 'more than two lines'
```

By feeding the file on the standard input of `wc`, we avoid the troublesome `cut`.